# Summing sections of dataframe in R

Tags: r

For a sample dataframe:

```
structure(list(id = 1:10, group.id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    x = c(2.12, 1.23, 2.36, 4.21, 2.36, NA, 2.36, 4.36, 1.23, 
    2.23), y = c(6.56, 2.36, NA, 4.36, 1.23, 8.56, 4.23, 5.36, 
    2.36, 1.23), z = c(4.36, NA, 5.23, 5.36, 1.23, 4.23, 1.23, 
    NA, 3.26, 2.23), group.x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), group.y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), group.z = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA)), .Names = c("id", "group.id", "x", "y", "z", "group.x", 
"group.y", "group.z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I wish to populate group.x/y/z with the mean of the values in columns x, y and z BY the group id.

So, the mean of the values in IDs 1,2,3 and 10 are averaged and populated in the corresponding columns "group.x", "group.y" and group.z".  This is subsequently done for groups b and c, filling in the rows.

Ideally I would like an additional table detailing the groups and the number of values and means in, so I could assess how representative the values are.  With my basic knowledge of R, I would just subset the dataframe and do the mean and counts for each section, however there must be a better way...  Any ideas?

Comment: It's better to provide your desired output too in order to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `data.table` to create new columns with `mean` value of 'x', 'y', 'z' grouped by the 'group.id' column.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' with `setDT(df1)` (or alternatively we can use `as.data.table` as suggested by @Ricardo Saporta.  One advantage would be the initial dataset remains unmodified.  I prefer to use `setDT` (just subjective)).  We don't need to create NA columns in the initial dataset.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, paste('group', c('x', 'y', 'z'), sep=".") := 
    lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), group.id, .SDcols=c('x','y','z')]
```

Assuming that we already have NA columns, make sure that the class would be the same i.e. 'numeric'

```
setDT(df1)[, 6:8 := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=6:8][, 
   paste('group', c('x', 'y', 'z'), sep=".") := 
   lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), group.id, .SDcols=c('x','y','z')]
```

Comment: I would suggest using `as.data.table` instead of `setDT`, especially for questions on Stack Overflow.  `setDT` modifies the original object, so there is no "undoing".  This will be surprising to those not familiar with `data.table`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta  I think `setDT` is a bit more faster than `as.data.table`.  That is one reason I use it, but you are right that it modify the original object

Comment: Thanks, but when I run the code of df1 I get the message: Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df1), , `:=`(paste("group", c("x", "y",  : 
  Type of RHS ('double') must match LHS ('logical'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)  Any ideas?

Comment: @KT_1 That is because the class of the already created column`group.x` and the mean value assigned are not matching.  Try the updated solution

Comment: @akrun, yes `setDT` absolutely is faster :)  It is precisely what gives it this speed that may be undesirable behavior to someone who is not familiar with many of the (deliberate) side effects in the data.table package.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I would also create a copy of the dataset before doing `setDT` in case the original dataset is needed i.e `df2 <- copy(df1)`

Comment: @akrun That's exactly my point. You do that because you are aware of the intricacies of `setDT`. When someone is reading SO or in general just learning, they may not be aware. So there are dangers in suggesting `setDT` over `as.data.table`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I fully agree with you, but I am a bit lazy to type `as.data.table`.  :-).  Also, to get the hang of data.table, they should use `setDT` instead of the slower version.  In some cases, I use `set` in a for loop as it is more memory efficient, although the `lapply(.SD,..` would be more compact.

Answer (score 1):

How about `dplyr`?

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  group_by(group.id)%>%
  mutate(group.x=mean(x,na.rm=T),
         group.y=mean(y,na.rm=T),
         group.z=mean(z,na.rm=T))
```

Comment: Suppose there are 100 columns, using this method may need a lot of typing.  `mutate_each` and `bind_cols` may be an alternative